# Route Not Working In Codeignator On Aws Server

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Route

**Code show here**

```
$route['validate'] = 'login/validate';
```

But When I Hit This Route Then I Get Error:

> The requested URL /validate was not found on this server.

Comment: show your login controller also

Comment: <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {


 public function index()
 {
     $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->view('login');
 }
 
 public function validate()
 {
    echo "Enter";
       }

Comment: Does the index route work?

Comment: Yes Index Route Work Perfectly

Comment: everything seems to be true.Can you tell the real link to see? And so where this route is called

Comment: http://18.237.80.247           Check This Link When I Click Login Button Then Route Redirect On $route['validate'] = 'login/validate'; And Controller Code I Already Sent You.

Comment: I think the problem is from the htaccess file

Comment: File this to change:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1